# Using concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecuter() with kwargs

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, keyword-argument

How can I use concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecuter().map with a list that contains a dictionary of kwargs?

Using a func with only one argument, I can use the executer like this:

```
import concurrent.futures

def one_arg(arg):
    print(arg)

arg_list = [1, 2, 3]

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executer:
    executer.map(one_arg, arg_list)

output:
1
2
3
```

Now, let's take a func with multiple input arguments:

```
def some_kwargs(kwarg_1, kwarg_2, kwarg_3):
    print('kwarg_1: {} - kwarg_2: {} - kwarg_3: {}'.format(kwarg_1, kwarg_2, kwarg_3))

kwargs = {"kwarg_1": "1_1", "kwarg_2": "1_2", "kwarg_3": "1_3"}
some_kwargs(**kwargs)

output:
'kwarg_1: 1_1 - kwarg_2: 1_2 - kwarg_3: 1_3'
```

Now, what I am really after is how to call `some_kwargs` using threading when I have a `list` of kwargs?

```
kwargs_list = [{"kwarg_1": "1_1", "kwarg_2": "1_2", "kwarg_3": "1_3"},
               {"kwarg_1": "2_1", "kwarg_2": "2_2", "kwarg_3": "2_3"},
               {"kwarg_1": "3_1", "kwarg_2": "3_2", "kwarg_3": "3_3"}]

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executer:
    executer.map(some_kwargs, **kwargs_list)  # TypeError: map() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a lambda function to wrap `some_kwargs`:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executer:
    executer.map(lambda x: some_kwargs(**x), kwargs_list)
```

Note that `**kwargs_list` raises the above `TypeError` as `kwargs_list` is a list, not a dict.